# Python Rest API user registration based on FastAPI framework

Tags: python, rest

I have written an API for a dating service. This part is related to user authentification, authorization, login and etc.

It uses FastAPI, which in turn is based on starlette web server.

You may wonder what is `fastapi.Depends...`. It's internally calling a passed function when the endpoint is requested to satisfy its dependencies. I don't know what is a problem to satisfy a dependencies manually, but just using it.

Here is my code, please give me any feedback.

```
import fastapi
import uvicorn
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
import config
import schemas
import database
import services
import crud
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    

app = fastapi.FastAPI(title='api', description='A very verbose API.', version='0.1')

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login", auto_error=False)  # Add GUI from to login

fastapi_http_errors = {

    'no_token_401': fastapi.HTTPException(
        status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Invalid token",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"}),

    'wrong_token_403': fastapi.HTTPException(
        status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
        detail="Wrong email or password",  # TODO wrong token ?
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"}, ),

    'not_found_404': fastapi.HTTPException(
        status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        detail="Interest not found"),

    'email_already_exists_409': fastapi.HTTPException(
        status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT,
        detail="Email already exists"),

    'double_voting_409': fastapi.HTTPException(
        status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT,
        detail="Same vote for the same interest"),

    'expired_410': fastapi.HTTPException(
        status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_410_GONE,
        detail="Confirmation link is expired"),

    'fatal_error_503': fastapi.HTTPException(
        status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
        detail="Unknown error"),
}


@app.post("/register", status_code=201, )
def register(
        user_log_in: schemas.UserLogIn,
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        if not crud.read_user_by(db, column='email', value=user_log_in.email):  # If email is new
            token = services.create_access_token(email=user_log_in.email,
                                                 expires_min=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
            services.send_email_confirm_link(token=token, endpoint='http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm-email')
            return crud.create_user(db=db, user=user_log_in, token=token)
        else:
            return fastapi_http_errors['email_already_exists_409']
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi_http_errors['fatal_error_503']


@app.get("/confirm-email", status_code=303, )
def confirm_email(
        token: str = fastapi.Query(...,
                                   min_length=64, max_length=256,
                                   description="jwt_token placed in url",
                                   example='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkc2IzMjFtcEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2MTAzNjY1MDV9.ZT0G5bHSNBdrh-onuAp4Q6m8mqWxfjBWbIg6GLJEAgk'),
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        if user := services.get_user_by_token(db=db, token=token):
            if user.created_datetime + timedelta(minutes=30) > datetime.now():  # TODO change minutes to days
                crud.update_user(db=db, user=user, column='is_active', value=True)
                return fastapi.responses.RedirectResponse(url=f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/me?token={token}")
            else:
                return fastapi_http_errors['expired_410']
        else:
            return fastapi_http_errors['wrong_token_403']
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi_http_errors['fatal_error_503']


@app.post("/login", response_model=schemas.Token)
def grant_token(
        form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = fastapi.Depends(),
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        if token := services.grant_token(db=db, email=form_data.username, password=form_data.password):
            return token
        else:
            return fastapi_http_errors['wrong_token_403']
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi_http_errors['fatal_error_503']


@app.post("/refresh-token",
          response_model=schemas.Token)
def refresh_token(
        token: str = fastapi.Depends(oauth2_scheme),
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        if token:
            if user := services.get_user_by_token(db=db, token=token):
                access_token = services.create_access_token(
                    email=user.email, expires_min=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
                crud.update_user(db=db, user=user, column='current_token', value=access_token)
                return 'Token successfully refreshed'
            else:
                return fastapi_http_errors['wrong_token_403']
        else:
            return fastapi_http_errors['no_token_401']
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi_http_errors['fatal_error_503']


@app.post("/logout")
def logout(token: str, db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        if token:
            if user := services.get_user_by_token(db=db, token=token):
                crud.update_user(db=db, user=user, column='current_token', value=None)  # Set token to None
                return f'Successfully logout user_id {user.id}'
            else:
                return fastapi_http_errors['wrong_token_403']
        else:
            return fastapi_http_errors['no_token_401']
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi_http_errors['fatal_error_503']


@app.get("/users/me", status_code=200)  # response model
def read_users_me(
        token: str = fastapi.Query(None),
        jwt_token: str = fastapi.Depends(oauth2_scheme),
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    """
      token: url_token indeed! REST requiring '-' instead of '_' in url,
      but python variable can't contain '-', unfortunately FastAPI doesn't converting it.
    """
    try:
        if token := (jwt_token or token):
            if user := services.get_user_by_token(db=db, token=token):
                return user
            else:
                return fastapi_http_errors['wrong_token_403']
        else:
            return fastapi_http_errors['no_token_401']
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi_http_errors['fatal_error_503']


@app.patch("/users/me", status_code=200)  # See PATCH vs PUT in module annotation.
def patch_users_me(
        column: str = fastapi.Query(..., description="Column to patch", example='email'),  # TODO restrict some columns
        value: str = fastapi.Query(..., description="New value", example='foo@gmail.com'),
        token: str = fastapi.Depends(oauth2_scheme),
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        if token:
            if user := services.get_user_by_token(db=db, token=token):
                crud.update_user(db=db, user=user, column=column, value=value)  # TODO test it
                return 'User successfully updated'
            else:
                return fastapi_http_errors['wrong_token_403']
        else:
            return fastapi_http_errors['no_token_401']
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi_http_errors['fatal_error_503']


@app.put("/users/me", status_code=200)  # See PATCH vs PUT in file annotation.
def put_users_me():
    pass


@app.delete("/users/me", status_code=200)  # response model
def delete_users_me(
        token: str = fastapi.Depends(oauth2_scheme),
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        if token := token:
            if user := services.get_user_by_token(db=db, token=token):
                crud.delete_user(db=db, user=user)
                return 'User successfully deleted'
            else:
                return fastapi_http_errors['wrong_token_403']
        else:
            return fastapi_http_errors['no_token_401']
    except Exception as e:
        raise fastapi_http_errors['fatal_error_503']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex edited

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for editing